# (undefined method `name' for #<User:0x00000005f63ee8>) Devise; Ruby on Rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have this error in heroku logs:
[image: Error from heroku logs]

Maybe this is because I have added name, surname and phone fields at registration? Locally my project is working fine, without problems.

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and   :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name, :surname, :phone
end
```

Devise registration form:

```
<div id="content">  
<h1 class="title">Reģistrēt jaunu profilu.</h1>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
<div class="virslauks"> 
    <span class="text2">
        <%= f.label :name, "Vārds:" %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %><br />
        <%= f.label :surname, "Uzvārds:" %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :surname %><br />
    </span>
</div>
<div class="virslauks"> 
    <span class="text2">
        <%= f.label :phone, "Telefona Nr.:" %><br />
        <%= f.phone_field :phone %>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="virslauks"> 
    <span class="text2">
        <%= f.label :email, "E-pasts:" %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email %>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="virslauks"> 
    <span class="text2">
        <%= f.label :password, "Parole:" %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password %><br />
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Vēlreiz parole:" %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </span>
</div>
<%= f.submit "Reģistrēties" %>
<% end %>
```

devise_create_users:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
create_table(:users) do |t|
  ## User details
  t.string :name,               :null => false, :default => ""
  t.string :surname,            :null => false, :default => ""
  t.integer :phone,            :null => false, :default => ""

  ## Database authenticatable
  t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  ## Trackable
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

  ## Encryptable
  # t.string :password_salt

  ## Confirmable
  # t.string   :confirmation_token
  # t.datetime :confirmed_at
  # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # t.datetime :locked_at

  ## Token authenticatable
  # t.string :authentication_token


  t.timestamps
end

add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
# add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
# add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
# add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end
end
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**

I have solved the problem. I simply added

> add_index :users, :name, :surname, :phone

in devise_create_users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `name` a column in your database?  Note, it is not there by default with `devise`.  If so, did you run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Yes, locally I ran `rake db:migrate`, but in heroku console `heroku run db:migrate`, so all should be working...

Comment: And as you can see I have name column in my User table.